# Ideas for application architecture on AWS (ECR + ECS Fargate + RDS + Lambda(?) )

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

I am a beginner in this and I am trying to figure out what would be the best architecture and workflow for the following use-case *(I am using React on front, and nodejs on backend, but this might be irrelevant considering this is a question regarding architecture)*:

### Use-case:

User lands on my page, where I have a table already filled with customers from RDS table. User has an option to either delete a customer (corresponding row) or edit that customer, and all the changes done on frontend should be recorded in a datebase so that next time when user visits the page he/she gets the latest database state. The problem that I have is that I am tasked with implementing this architecture using services such as ECR, ECS ( I opted for Fargate, as serverless solution ), RDS but I have no idea how the workflow should look like and what role would lambdas have in case they are necessary ( or are they? ). Considering also that I need to use RDS, which option PostgreSQL/MySQL/Aurora would be the best fit for this use-case?

---

### What I've tried up till now:

What I've managed to do up till now, is I dockerized my react app (containing the the frontend table where customers will go), pushed it to ECR, created a cluster inside of ECS with a most default task definition holding the ecsTaskExecution Role, a container holding the image from ECR, and a service that's responsible for running the task. I also added Application Load Balancer in front of the ECS cluster so that my react app can be reached from browser (planning to add my personal domain).

---

## Problem:

I am clueless as to who should "speak" to who when it comes to all these individual services, how many containers should I have, are lambdas as functions that will do the deleting & updating needed, or do they only serve as triggers which will leave all the processing to ECS tasks? Basically I am having struggles with imagining the whole picture of the workflow. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Your backend could either be Lambda or ECS/Fargate. It doesn't sound like you would need both. Are you trying to learn AWS, or just setup this application in the cheapest way possible? You could build something that ties together all the services you mentioned as a learning exercise, but your app sounds trivially small and could probably be hosted virtually for free if you made the appropriate design decisions. The question about Postgres vs MySQL is purely up to you, either of those can handle what you describe without breaking a sweat.

Comment: @MarkB Just trying to learn AWS, and implement different use-cases while trying to learn more about the services that I am currently interested in. So yea, in a way i am trying to build something that ties together all the services that I've mentioned :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after a few days of experimenting and reading, this is the architecture I came up with:

ReactJS application hosted on S3, NodeJS application ( Express server ) containerized on docker, pushed to ECR and then on ECS (I choose EC2 Linux + Networking for ECS cluster and then according to that I choose EC2 for Task which is responsible for running my ECR container), while for a database I choose MySQL inside of RDS.

So basically the communication is happening between **S3 -> ECS -> RDS ( ReactJS -> NodeJS -> MySQL ).**